# Loading a IEnumerable<XElement> collection

Tags: asp.net, xelement

```
XElement root = XElement.Load(xmlReader);

IEnumerable<XElment> items = root.Elements("?????????");
```

Where the ???? is, can I add a path or it has to be a single xml element name?

ie. can I do  /blah/blah2/asdf ?

Answer (score 3):

*????* should be a single xml element name.

Strictly saying, The `Elements()` methods accepts an `XName` argument. Fortunately, there is an implicit conversion from `string` to `XName`.

```
XName name = "Book";
XName name2 = "{http://schemas.company.com/books}Book"; // XName with a namespace
```

To select a *path*, use the extension methods from the `System.Xml.XPath` namespace (`System.Xml.Linq` assembly):

```
IEnumerable<XElment> items = root.XPathSelectElements("Books/Author");
```

Answer (score 1):

No, the parameter to the Elements extension method needs to be a single element name (an XName actually, but if you don't need namespaces, just pass the element name as a string), not an XPath.

If you want to select XElements using XPath, there is also [an extension method for that](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb342176.aspx). Include System.Xml.XPath and do:

```
IEnumerable<XElement> items = root.XPathSelectElements("your/xpath");
```

Answer (score 0):

If you try to pass an XPath you will generate this exception:

> An unhandled exception of type
>   'System.Xml.XmlException' occurred in
>   System.Xml.dll
>
> Additional information: The '/'
>   character, hexadecimal value 0x2F,
>   cannot be included in a name.

You must pass the element name as a string.  That string is implicity converted to an [`XName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xname.aspx) type that has restrictions over what characters can and cannot be in the string (`/`,`<`, `>`, etc.).